# Why spring boot modify jar in source resources?

Tags: java, maven-plugin

My spring boot construction like this:

```
/src/main/resources/
  +- /lib
     +- logback-classic-1.1.9-source.jar
     +- logback-classic-1.1.9.jar
```

and the pom I used :

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>  
       <resource>  
           <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>  
           <filtering>true</filtering>  
           <includes>  
               <include>**/*</include>  
           </includes>  
       </resource>    
   </resources> 
</build>
```

and I put the spring boot project packaging into war file.
When I use mvn clean install to get the war file, what is shocking at me is the 
`logback-classic-1.1.9-source.jar` and `logback-classic-1.1.9.jar` in the war has been changed!!
The two jars in the source lib file are all 248KB but, in war file, they changed 
to 418KB and 420KB!! The jar is broken, 7-zip can not unzip the jar!

I don't know why. Could any one help me? thank you!

also I can use

```
<excludes>
    <exclude>**/*.jar</exclude> 
</excludes>
```

to exclude move jar into the war, but I just want to know what is wrong with my code let the spring boot change my jar in resources.

I also try the spring project, in that case, all things are OK! My jar didn't change in the war file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the libs underneath the *src/main/resources* path and they are copied with *filtering* set to true. So in the process of copying the resources, they will be modified if they contain String in the form `${...}`.

The first solution would be to not include the jars as resources. Do you reall need the source jar in your final artefact? If not, remove this *lib* folder and add a dependency to the logback-classic jar:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
  <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

The latest version by the way is 1.2.3. Using this will put the logback-jar where it belongs when you build the project with `mvn package` and is the normal way of adding dependent libraries.

If you really want to keep this in the resources, you should exclude the *lib* directory from the filtering and copy it unfiltered:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>lib</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/lib</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: i change the filtering to false,the problem is solved.you are right ! thank you very muck!

Comment: then please be so kind and accept accept the answer (clicking the grey checkmark on the left.

Comment: thank you, but the right way on StackOverflow for somebody who asks a question and qho gets an answer to this question is to accept the answer. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. As a new user you do not yet have the vote privilege.